# C++ Threads and Member Function Overloading With Multiple Arguments

Tags: c++, multithreading, methods, casting, overloading

(Note that the following is an just example based on real code)

Foo.hpp:

```
#include <thread.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Foo
{
    private:
        std::thread t;
        std::string s;
        int x;
        int y;
   public:
        Foo();
        Foo(std::string s, int x, int y);
        void init();
        void init(std::string s, int x, int y);
};
```

Foo.cpp:

```
#include "Foo.cpp"

Foo::Foo()
{
   this->thread = std::thread(static_cast<void (Foo::*)()>(&Foo::init), this);
}

Foo::Foo(std::string s, int x, int y)
{
    this->thread = std::thread(static_cast<void (Foo::*)()>(&Foo::init), this, s, x, y);
}

// Foo::init() and Foo::init(std::string s, int x, int y) definitions
```

This causes g++ to output quite a lot of errors, the most notable of which is likely

```
no match for call to '(std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<void (Foo::*, std::basic_string<char>, int, int)>) ()' (*upCall)();
                                                                                                        ^
```

So what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You are using the same cast for both functions, when they have different number of parameters.

Comment: So how do I write the casts correctly?

Comment: Never (!) use a thread (member) constructed in a class referencing the instance of that class (it's circular in terms of 'destruction' and 'join')

Comment: Normally you don't need the cast at all. Here it is used to select one of the overloads, so `static_cast<void (Foo::*)(std::string, int, int)>`. Or change the name of one of the functions...

Comment: Ok, but moving it to `int main()` or another class still doesn't help me solve this.

Comment: It is typically easier to write and read when you use a lambda: `std::thread( [=]{ init(); } )` and `std::thread( [=]{ init(s, x, y); } )`

Comment: @BoPersson That worked thank you!

Comment: It _does_ however crash on runtime. Though that might be a seperate error related to what DieterLücking was reffering to

Comment: @dyp That also worked, but likewise crashed at runtime. Thank you though.

Comment: I managed to solve the crashing issue as well. I was simply calling thread.join() is the wrong place.